# How to inverse vlookup in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I have a table with key values pairs, keys in A and values in B:

```
    A   B
  +-------
1 | a   x
2 | b   y
3 | c   z
```

Getting the value for a key can be done with the `vlookup` function:

```
=VLOOKUP("a";A1:B3;2;FALSE)
```

But how to perform the inverse lookup? How to get the key for a value?

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AotCeBHq3wFtdENHOG8tMjJyTFZMdDl0WDFiUWh4MUE&usp=sharing) is an example.

*Update: I added Wolfs answer.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example, try the following:

```
=index(A:A,match(C1,B:B,0))
```

It was found on the [Google product forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/hKbBWDZmhRo).

Answer (score 1):

This blog post by Ben Collins has an answer that exactly fits what you need.  Basically, you can force the equation to read the range backwards and *believe* your right column is the first one, and your left column is the second one.

This is what your formula would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP("a";{B$1:B$3, A$1:A$3};2;FALSE)
```

[Blog post with more detail here](http://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/vlookup-left/).

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup is a lookup function which, like an Excel's INDEX-MATCH, searches for a value in the leftmost column of one tabel and then retrieves information from a column to its right. In contrast to INDEX-MATCH excel function, VLOOKUP offers more control over the retrieved information by specifying on what should happen when it doesn't find the key sought - return nothing (the default), insert new data found below or above as defined by another search term, or just simply enter a "zero" value when searching for positive number
Answer:

Inverse Vlookup Tableau function
Equal to = Tableau("vlookup", "row of column A you want lookup from", "column/Sheet with values that go into table")
Almost equal to -1 * Tableau("vlookup"...) = TRUE.

It's important to have the correct formulas and syntax to get your desired results, hence why this function is called an "Inverse Vlookup".
[Here](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-excel/) is a helpful article about Excel Vlookups to read before you get started